# How get a peewee DateField as string in a query returning tuples

Tags: python, orm, peewee

I'm attempting to make a query with  a DateField in peewee and returning the result as Tuples. I'm using SQLite as database,  the query works ok but in the DateField is returning the DateTime object instead  the date as string.

This is the code:

```
import peewee as pw

db = pw.SqliteDatabase(':memory:')


class Person(pw.Model):
    name = pw.CharField()
    birthday = pw.DateField(formats=['%Y-%m-%d'])

    class Meta:
        database = db

db.create_tables([Person])

alice = Person(name = 'Alice', birthday = '1995-1-21')
robert = Person(name = 'Robert', birthday = '1978-1-22')
john = Person(name = 'John', birthday = '1995-1-20')
mary = Person(name = 'Mary', birthday = '1989-1-18')
emily = Person(name = 'Emily', birthday = '2003-12-28')
alice.save()
robert.save()
john.save()
mary.save()
emily.save()

query = Person.select(Person.name,
                      Person.birthday).tuples()


for rows in query:
    print(rows)
```

So what I get is this:

```
('Alice', datetime.date(1995, 1, 21))
('Robert', datetime.date(1978, 1, 22))
('John', datetime.date(1995, 1, 20))
('Mary', datetime.date(1989, 1, 18))
('Emily', datetime.date(2003, 12, 28))
[Finished in 85ms]
```

I would get  the result of query like:

```
('Alice', '1995-1-21')
('Robert', '1978-1-22')
('John', '1995-1-20')
('Mary', '1989-1-18')
('Emily', '2003-12-28')
```

There is a way I could achive that?

I tried converting the list of tuples to list of list:

```
qrylist = [list(items) for items in query]
```

but the result is the same:

```
['Alice', datetime.date(1995, 1, 21)]
['Robert', datetime.date(1978, 1, 22)]
['John', datetime.date(1995, 1, 20)]
['Mary', datetime.date(1989, 1, 18)]
['Emily', datetime.date(2003, 12, 28)]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are more idiomatic ways to do this than what you posted:

```
Person.select(Person.name, Person.birthday.cast('text')).tuples()[:]
[('Alice', '1995-01-21'),
 ('Robert', '1978-01-22'),
 ('John', '1995-01-20'),
 ('Mary', '1989-01-18'),
 ('Emily', '2003-12-28')]
```

Answer (score 0):

While Creating list, you can convert datetime object to string in any format you want -
For e.g.,

```
strdatetime = list_of_datetimeobject[i].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

The type of strdatetime is String. Now replace the DateTime object with strdatetime.

Answer (score -1):

I ending up replacing directly the datetime object in the list created by:

```
qrylist = [list(items) for items in query]

for rows in range(len(qrylist)):
        qrylist[rows-1][1] = qrylist[rows-1][1].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

So now the list query is:

```
['Alice', '1995-01-21']
['Robert', '1978-01-22']
['John', '1995-01-20']
['Mary', '1989-01-18']
['Emily', '2003-12-28']
```